# TrustManagerFactory and setting the SSLSocketFactory

Tags: android, ssl

I have a SSLSocketFactory and a TrustManagerFactory as shown below:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        LogUtils.log("SSL: did init TrustManagerFactory with trust keyStore");
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

What are the implications of setting the context TrustManagers to null?

so

changing:

```
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

to this:

```
context.init(null, null, null);
```

Comment: `null` for the trust manager will use the default TrustManager, which might not be an "X509" TM (it's "PKIX" in recent versions of Oracle JREs, not sure about Android), and which might be initialised with a different trust store (since your code doesn't show where you've loaded it from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Java api documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init%28javax.net.ssl.KeyManager%5B%5D,%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager%5B%5D,%20java.security.SecureRandom%29) it provides more details about the method `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random)`. Assuming that the Android framework has not changed the implementation, passing `null` for the tm input will use the Android preinstalled trust managers for the server SSL certificate acceptance.